# How to custom format a string in SSRS

Tags: vb.net, function, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm experimenting with custom formatting of strings and I wrote a simple function to do this task as shown below.

**Function written inside the "Code" pane of the report properties:**

```
Function FormatProject(Project AS String) AS String
    IF (Project Is Nothing) Then
        Return Nothing
    Else
        Return Format(Project, "## #####")
    End If
End Function
```

**Input:** PR12345

**Expected Output:** PR 12345

**Actual Output:** ## #####

I'm using the hash signs because I wrote a similar function to customize a phone number and it worked for that but perhaps it only works with numeric data types and I might need to use a different placeholder.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Left](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y050k1wb(v=vs.90).aspx) and [Mid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05e63829(v=vs.90).aspx) functions to help here (I imagine [Substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/substring-ssis-expression) is supported too):

```
Return Left(Project, 2) & " " & Mid(Project, 3, (Len(Project) - 2))
```